# Using AWS OpenSearch internal users/roles from application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-opensearch

How many of you are using Amazon's OpenSearch Security (internal users and roles) for your OpenSearch indexes, and do you have many users and roles (>100,000)?

We are trying to use OpenSearch Security in our .NET Framework (C#) web app but need to support potentially 100,000+ users, 100,000+ roles, and up to 500,000 documents per user. In trying to run proof-of-concept load tests, we have run into performance issues.

How are you adding/updating users and roles? We have found that adding a lot of roles at one time is terribly slow. Has anyone else seen this behavior?

If you aren't using the internal users/roles security, what kind of security are you using and do you find it performant?

TIA!

Comment: How are you creating users, and roles? API, dashboard or file? What instance type are you running OpenSearch on?

Comment: We want to create users/roles using the API (or other client) programmatically. We were running tests of the code on an OpenSearch instance in Docker, but we just spun up one in AWS that is a c5.4xlarge.search instance type, and that does seem to help.

Comment: The API documentation for creating users/roles/rolemapping, particularly using the Patch methods, using the OpenSearch .NET Client, is lacking. We are learning that there is more capability there than the docs show.

Comment: Lacking how? Your question seems to be broad, I would recommend making it more focused to only need 1 answer.